# Access a private instance from a jump server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I've created a new instance in AWS vpc with only private IP, I want to access the new instance from the jumpbox.

How do I enable the handshake between these two instances?

Note: I've created a new pem file for the new instance.

Comment: When you say "access the new instance", what type of access do you want? Are you wanting to SSH to it, or forward a port? What have you tried so far and what problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

To allow your public bastion to connect to your private instance the following steps must be completed:

- Update the security group for your private instance to allow SSH access from the private IP address of the jump box. The most reliable way to do this is to reference the security group of the jump box as the source of traffic in the private instances security group.
- If you have attached the private subnet to a custom NACL, then you must whitelist the private IP range of the jump box.
- Connect to the private instance using a PEM that is setup on the server using either SSH (for Linux) or via RDP (for Windows) on your private server.